# Folders 'locked' to FTP access on Win Server 2003 Standard - firewall issue but how to resolve

Tags: windows-server-2003, firewall, ftp

I have a weird issue which is just affecting one of many sites on my Windows 2003 Standard server (running IIS6).  I'm not a server admin by the way, but the company who manage my server don't seem able to help :(

Basically, there is a site on the server which has an 'admin' folder which contains some simple content management system files.  When I try to access this folder by FTP my FTP client won't connect.  I've tried several clients, using both active and passive connections, and they work fine except when trying to open this folder.  It's like it is locked to FTP connections.  Weirdly, if I copy the folder and rename it 'admin2' for example, the same thing happens - I can't access this folder via FTP either.  If I create a new folder on the server, e.g. 'admin3' I can access it, but when I copy the files into the folder it stops working again.  Would a corrupt file cause this?  There are thousands of files in there so I'm not sure how I'd resolve that.

Anyhow, after trying loads of things, I eventually got the admins to disable the firewall temporarily on the server, which resovled the issue completely.  So it's as if there's a firewall block on something in that folder which prevents FTP access to the folder.  I can still access the files via the website (it runs okay in the browser) but just won't connect by FTP.

Can anyone tell what might be the issue here, and help me correct it?  Like I say, I'm a total novice when it comes to server admin, so please bear that in mind!  I just have no choice as my providers don't seem able to help and it's starting to frustrate me having to make code changes direct on the server because FTP isn't working for this folder.

Thanks folks!

Comment: have you checked the NTFS permissions themselves on those folders on the server?

Comment: Yes, permissions have been checked.  The key is that it works when the firewall is disabled but problem starts again when the firewall is re-enabled. So it's definitely related to the firewall but I've no idea why it would be doing this or how to stop it!

Comment: If you can get the firewall rules on the server that might help troubleshoot which rule is causing the issue then.